# MSVisio Characters custom color

Tags: c#, .net, vba, visio

I know, that I can change color of all text in shape this way:

```
Shape.CellsU["Char.Color"].FormulaForceU = "RGB(255,255,255)";
```

There is also way to change color of certain characters in shape this way:

```
Characters.Begin = 2;
Characters.End = 5;    
Characters.set_CharProps((short)MSVisio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor, (short)MSVisio.VisDefaultColors.visRed;);
```

But I can't find any way to pass custom RGB (or HEX or any type) value of color to just certain characters in shape. I don't want to cut shape into little shapes.

Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CharProps` property allows you to set an index into the predefined document colors collection.  For a custom RGB you can set the corresponding cell formula by first getting the row index with [CharPropsRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.characters.charpropsrow) like this:

```c#
    var shp = vApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem;
    var shpChars = shp.Characters;

    shpChars.Begin = 2;
    shpChars.End = 5;
    //shpChars.set_CharProps((short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor, (short)Visio.VisDefaultColors.visRed);

    var targetRow = shpChars.CharPropsRow[0];
    shp.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter, 
                 targetRow,
                 (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor].FormulaU = "RGB(40,220,40)";
```

and that should give you similar results to this:
[image]

[Update] The above assumes you're targeting existing formating and changing it.  To add new runs you can use CharProps first to add the row and then the CharPropsRow to target that new run.  So you can run this code against a new page:

```c#
    var vPag = vApp.ActivePage;
    var shp = vPag.DrawRectangle(3,3,5,4);
    shp.Text = "GoodMorning";

    var shpChars = shp.Characters;

    shpChars.Begin = 0;
    shpChars.End = 4;
    var targetRow = shpChars.CharPropsRow[(short)Visio.VisCharsBias.visBiasLetVisioChoose];
    shp.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter,
                 targetRow,
                 (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor].FormulaU = "RGB(220,40,40)";

    shpChars.Begin = 4;
    shpChars.End = 11;
    shpChars.set_CharProps((short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor, (short)Visio.VisDefaultColors.visBlack);
    targetRow = shpChars.CharPropsRow[(short)Visio.VisCharsBias.visBiasLetVisioChoose];
    shp.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter,
                 targetRow,
                 (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor].FormulaU = "RGB(40,200,40)";
```

...and this should result in the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer :) I don't know why, but this changes color to all characters in shape and every next change to other characters color in this shape is not made. 

So instead of this: {RED}Good{/RED} {BLUE}Morning{/BLUE}
it make this: {RED}Good Morning{/RED}

Comment: Sorry, I'd assumed you were targeting a shape with existing formating (multiple Character section rows).  If you don't then you need to add a new run first by using the set_CharProps, perhaps setting it to visBlack, and then the follow it with your custom row calls.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This finally solved my problem.